# installing fedora 21/22 on a raid?

Tags: linux, raid, fedora, fedora-21, fedora-22

i created a RAID0 device on two disks using `mdadm --create /dev/md0 --level=stripe...`

when i boot the fedora 21 installer, i can see it mounting and dismounting that raid on the console 4 log (reserved for storage logging)

but the anaconda installer only shows me the two physical disks and nothing else.

if i jump to another console and mount the raid there (`mdadm --assembly --scan`) and refresh the disks on the installer, it will still only show the physical devices.

is there any hope of installing fedora21 or 22 on that raid?

my partition scheme is as follow:

```
/dev/sda1 - 1Gb (for boot)
/dev/sda2 - 2Gb swap
/dev/sda3 - 128Gb raid
/dev/sdb1 - 2Gb swap
/dev/sdb2 - 128Gb raid
```

Comment: hum. if i mount md0, create a ext4 fs with a label "X" and then go back to installer, refresh, and select both disks, i will get the raid labeled as "X" and with the full size showing up there... so i think that is the answer?

Comment: spoke too soon. cannot make the same happen now. now the raid partitions do not even show up on the list...